# Yii: Using GROUP BY Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I want to implement `GROUP BY` clause of SQL using Yii. Here I faced problem of returning only first row instead of all rows.

```
    $connection = Yii::app()->db; 
    $sql = "SELECT group_name FROM  `authitem` GROUP BY group_name";             
    $command = $connection->createCommand($sql); 
    $row = $command->queryRow();            
    print_r($row);
    $res = array(); 
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) { 
       $res[] = array('label' => $key, 'value' => $val); 
    } 
    print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
 $row = $command->queryRow();
```

try like this,

```
 $row = $command->queryAll();
```